# How do you get a BST file to support natbib cite* commands

Tags: natbib

I have heavily modified an existing *.bst* file (`apalike2`) to get the format working perfectly.  However, an editor I'm working with tells me that the first time a multi-author citation is used, I need to give all of the authors in the citation.

I thought "no problem, I'll just add longnamesfirst".  I tried that, and it didn't work, and further research leads me to find out that a *.bst* file needs specific support for that feature to work, and `apalike` doesn't have that support.

I have *used* LaTeX for a long time, but am not an expert.  The way that packages work internally have always been a mystery to me.  I've managed to hack at the `apalike2` *.bst* to get it to work how I want, but I can't find the hook to support `longnamesfirst`, or even the `*`-version of the `\cite` commands.  If anyone can give me even a nudge in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.   Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Mico - there are no errors or warnings when I use longnamesfirst.  It is part of natbib docs that state that cite* commands perform the same as the normal cite commands if long names are not supported in the BST file, so there's no reason for a warning - that's just part of what it does.  

I've also tried using citestyle (\citestyle{plainnat}), but that doesn't seem to work either, though I could be using it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You mention using a heavily modified version of the style file `apalike2`. It's not clear from your description whether the style file's incompatibility with `natbib`'s `longnamesfirst` option was present even before the modifications to `apalike2` were applied of if it's maybe caused by the modifications. (My guess is that it's the former, but we can't be entirely certain.)

The only suggestion that comes readily to my mind is to create a bibliography style file from scratch using the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package. The `makebst` utility -- started by typing

```
latex makebst
```

at a command prompt -- uses a multiple query/multiple choice format to find out all formatting requirements and then creates a new style file for you. A big plus is that because the utility was written by the author of the `natbib` package, using it alongside `natbib` (and, if needed, its `longnamesfirst` option) is seemless.